# I've completed Masters of Engineering in Computer Science from India, can I apply for MBA in Canada?

Tags: immigration, canada

I've​ heard that, Canada Government will reject these kind of files, if already masters is completed and applying for another masters. But that's MBA-IT and now I want to be in Management side in my career.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that the govt will reject a visa if you have been accepted into a valid university/college,have the required funds and all your documents are in order. Visa requirements have been further loosened in the last few months, so you need not worry if things are in order.